# Loading AHN files correctly into MicroDEM?

Tags: coordinate-system, netherlands

In the netherlands we have the ahn elevation data files(to be found on: http://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/ahn2/atom/ahn2_05m_ruw.xml) (based on rd projection).

If i imort these files into microdem by clicking:

file-->open-->open dem

acknowledge the projection/date (amersfoort / rd new | amersfoort)

next, at the pick projection parameters, selecting

-utm zone 31
-northern hemisphere
-wgs 84
- clicking ok

although the coordinate should be in the 31u ...... it is 30nzk.

What am i doing wrong?

I use microdem in order to create Dted files. So if someone has an better option....